# She has bought some cloth.She will make/is going to make herself a blouse

Tags: future-tense, present-continuous, will-vs-going-to

> She has bought some cloth.She will make/is going to make herself a blouse.

My Approach:

I am confused here which to use.I think both can be used in reference to action whether she does in future or she is going to do it now?

Am I right in my approach?Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: A suggestion: use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) to ask questions of almost a similar kind.

Answer (score 1):

*is going to* is the marker for something in the near future, or something that's about to happen.

*will* is the future tense marker, and the future tense has no such specification.

Essentially, use *is going to* when she's about to do it, while *will* can be used to mean at a later time.